# C strcpy into an array of strings in shared memory

Tags: c, shared-memory, arrays

I want (or need) to do something along the lines of

```
char **my_array = malloc(1000*64);
strcpy(arr[0], "test");
```

While I know that arr[0] isn't pointing to a separate piece of allocated memory, I thought one  should be able to copy a string into it like this (yet it segs). This works

```
arr[0] = "test";
```

However that is not going to work, for my actual goal is to do this in shared memory.

```
shm_array = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, 1000 * 64, IPC_CREAT | 0644);
my_array = (char**) shmat(shm_array, (void**)0, 0);
```

Actually my question could be rephrased to: "How do you create an array of strings in shared memory?". I tried creating 1000 separate "string" shared memory segments, but apart of that it did not work it also seems wrong. Moreover, I thought one should simply be able to write into a big shared memory segment using relative pointer offsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create one single piece of memory and write to specific offsets:

```
char * const buf = malloc(HUGE);

strcpy(buf + offset1, "hello");
strcpy(buf + offset2, "world");
```

It'd probably be better to use `strncpy` and pass a size of `HUGE - offset` along to make sure you don't run over the end. Managing the offsets is your own responsibility. Or you can use `strncat`, if efficiency doesn't matter so much.

Comment: This was what I was actually trying to accomplish. Works with the shared memory segment as well.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are looking for a 2D array 1000 by 64. If this is indeed the case, you can do this:

```
struct shared_1000_by_64 {
    char strings[1000][64];
};

struct shared_1000_by_64 *shared = malloc(sizeof(struct shared_1000_by_64));
for (int i = 0 ; i != 1000 ; i++) {
    strcpy(shared->strings[i], "test");
}
```

This uses the standard trick of preventing the array from [*decaying into a pointer*](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically allocate an array of 64-character arrays, then use a pointer to an array rather than a pointer to a pointer:

```
char (*my_array)[64] = malloc(1000 * sizeof my_array[0]);
strcpy(my_array[0], "test");
```

or for the shared-memory case,

```
shm_array = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, 1000 * sizeof my_array[0], IPC_CREAT | 0644);
my_array = shmat(shm_array, NULL, 0);
```